# How to fix "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here's the JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mostthingsweb/cRayJ/1/

I'll include my code and then explain what's wrong

Here's my HTML header to show that everything should be linked:

```
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <link rel='stylesheet' href='test.css'/>
        <script src='test.js'></script>
    </head>
```

Here's the CSS:

```
.draggable {
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
    font-size: .9em;
}
.ui-widget-header p, .ui-widget-content p {
    margin: 0;
}
#snaptarget {
    height: 140px;
}
body, html {
    background: url('http://i.imgur.com/FBs3b.png') repeat;
}
```

Here's the JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#draggable5").draggable({
        grid: [80, 80]
    });
});
```

So the grid will launch and the paragraph will be there, however if I try to drag it, it won't work. When I inspect the page it gives me an error saying: "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function" that points to line 2 of my JS code. What am I doing wrong?

Here's the whole HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='test.css'/>
    <script src='test.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="demo">
    <div id="draggable5" class="draggable ui-widget-content">
        <p>I snap to a 80 x 80 grid</p>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Works perfectly for me in Chrome 35.0.1916.153

Comment: check whether `jqruery ui` is loaded or not... maybe it failed to load due to some network issue...

Comment: Can you create an example for us that fails? A working example doesn't help much.

Comment: Well that's the problem... It'll work in JSFiddle but it won't if I write it on my own and launch it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I pasted the code you've submitted into a local HTML file and it works fine for me (I did not add the test.js but pasted the code in script tags just before the closing body tag.
Here's the entire file (tested in Chrome only)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='test.css'/>
    <style type="text/css">            
        .draggable {
            width: 80px;
            height: 80px;
            float: left;
            margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
            font-size: .9em;
        }
        .ui-widget-header p, .ui-widget-content p {
            margin: 0;
        }
        #snaptarget {
            height: 140px;
        }
        body, html {
            background: url('http://i.imgur.com/FBs3b.png') repeat;
        }            
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="demo">
        <div id="draggable5" class="draggable ui-widget-content">
            <p>I snap to a 80 x 80 grid</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#draggable5").draggable({
                grid: [80, 80]
            });
        });
    </script>       
</body>
```

Comment: This worked for me as well... There must be some crazy linking problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem might be that you're loading jquery and your js files in the head of your code. When it reads your js, it's looking for $(#draggable5), but draggable5 hasn't loaded yet, so it's an empty selector. Try moving your scripts to just before the close of your body element.

Comment: And you're loading test.js after all of the jquery scripts are loaded?

Comment: Yes (space filler for comment length permission)

Comment: Everything you've posted looks just fine, hence why your code works on jsfiddle. There must be something else in there interfering.